# Data Attribute added to block from Content Type field

Tags: entities, nodes, blocks

So this is a very complex series of questions. I am brand new to module development (and PHP for that matter).

I have a content type called "Parallax Block" with 4 fields: a title, an image, a selection from a dropdown (Direction) and a body.

My ultimate goal is to have a module set up where every time a content type is generated, it creates a block with the Title and Body fields inside, but with the Direction and Image values placed as data attributes on each of the primary block divs. For example, a block called StackExchange with data-image="/path/whatever/se.png" and data-direction="top-to-bottom".

How can I dynamically create blocks based on the number of a content type, and have new blocks generated every time that a new piece of Parallax Block content is created?

As you can see in my linked module, I have gotten the appropriate nodes and variables from each Parallax Block. I'm trying to figure out how I can loop through and create blocks with dynamic names.

Furthermore, I am having difficulty getting a block template override functional that would be able to print out the appropriate values in the data attribute fields in the template file. How can I get these variables and insert them into each block?

I know that's a lot, so any resources that you can point me to would be a great help.

Here's the module as it currently exists.
https://bitbucket.org/mattcoker/parallax-block/

Comment: Are you sure that you really want a new block in the block interface each time that a node is created? I would guess that what you really want is one block that shows those information dynamically, depending on the context.

Comment: Yes. The ultimate goal is not to have  20+ blocks on the site. I want to be able to have an interface to creating anywhere between 3-5 blocks that will end up being full width blocks with a parallax background image.